# Removing numbers from Elasticsearch tokens

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

The text I'm analyzing in Elasticsearch-6 has a number of numbers that I'm not interested in, but I can't figure out how to remove them. Thank is, my search for tokens will bring back zip codes or times or years. There are few enough different years that I could add them to the stopwords possibly. But there's too many of the others to filter them out that way.

I did try writing a custom filter:

```
"char_filter": {
                "number_filter": {
                        "type": "pattern_replace",
                        "pattern": "\\d+",
                        "replacement": " "
            }
```

But when I tried to add it in the settings, I received the following error:

> Failed to get setting group for [index.analysis.analyzer.] setting prefix and setting [index.analysis.analyzer.char_filter] because of a missing '.'

Here's the whole settings portion of my configuration (note: it worked before I added the number replacer):

```
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "t_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "t_tokenizer"            
                },
                "major_words_analyzer": {
                        "type": "standard",
                        "stopwords": "_english_"
                },
                "char_filter": [
                        "number_filter"        
                ]
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "t_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "standard"        
                }        
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "number_filter": {
                        "type": "pattern_replace",
                        "pattern": "\\d+",
                        "replacement": " "
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the relevant field setup:

```
    },  
    "narrative": {
      "type": "text",
      "store": "true",
      "analyzer": "t_analyzer",
      "fielddata": "true",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    },
    "narrativePhrases": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "major_words_analyzer",
      "fielddata": "true",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
```

EDIT: What I'm doing afterwards is this:

```
    POST /test_narrative/_search?size=0
    {
        "aggs": {
            "incidents_by_month":{
                "date_histogram":{
                    "field":"eventDate",
                    "interval":"month",
                    "min_doc_count" : 5
                },
                "aggs":{
                    "top_phrases":{
                        "significant_text": {
                          "field": "narrative",
                          "size": 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm still having numbers in the return values:

```
    {
            "key": "personally",
            "doc_count": 3,
            "score": 5.22625236294896,
            "bg_count": 36
          },
          {
            "key": "2011",
            "doc_count": 4,
            "score": 2.4786045712321703,
            "bg_count": 132
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misplaced the `char_filter` in the above settings.

According to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html), `char_filter` is one of the parameters of a `custom analyzer` you'd be creating, so therefore it must be inside the `t_analyzer` and/or `major_words_analyzer` depending on your requirements. For e.g.

```
"t_analyzer":{  
   "tokenizer":"t_tokenizer",
   "char_filter":[  
      "number_filter"
   ]
}
```

If you intend to use `char_filter` on both analyzers, that means your settings has to be in the below manner.

```
PUT numberindex
{  
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "analyzer":{  
            "t_analyzer":{  
               "tokenizer":"t_tokenizer",
               "char_filter":[  
                  "number_filter"
               ]
            },
            "major_words_analyzer":{  
               "type":"standard",
               "stopwords":"_english_",
               "char_filter":[  
                  "number_filter"
               ]
            }
         },
         "tokenizer":{  
            "t_tokenizer":{  
               "type":"standard"
            }
         },
         "char_filter":{  
            "number_filter":{  
               "type":"pattern_replace",
               "pattern":"\\d+",
               "replacement":""
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I'm not understanding what this should be doing. I'm expecting the text to be filtered on load. But I'm still seeing digits when I aggregate terms.

Comment: Hey @amracel, could you update the question with a sample data how it appears now and what is it you want to search and accordingly what your expected query result would be? Looking at your question, error and configuration/settings, I've added the above answer which would resolve that issue.

Comment: I've added my query and showed what I'm getting. I did try your change and am still getting the same (type of) results.

Comment: @amracel Have you tried deleting the index and reindexed the data back-in? And if so, could you share me your mapping details i.e. update the question with it? I've created a sample index with the above settings and it does work as expected for me.

Comment: It resoved issue.